# C how to identify function exist or not

Tags: c

I have the following code in c :

```
char tag34[32]={0} ,tag16104[32]={0} ,tag43[16]={0} ,tag37[32]={0} ;
char tag35[8]={0} , tag150[8]={0} , tag11[32]={0} , tag41[32]={0};
char tag48[32]={0} , tag207[32]={0} , tag55[32]={0} ;
char tag167[32]={0} , tag200[32]={0} , tag44[32]={0} ;
char tag151[16]={0} , tag32[16]={0} , tag31[16]={0}  ;
char tag379[32]={0},  tag372[16]={0} , tag58[128]={0} ; 
char tag16710[32]={0},tag16724[32]={0} ;

for(int idx=0;idx<inum;idx++){
    if( strlen(ArrLeftVar[idx]) < 1 )
        break ;
    if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"34") == 0 ){ 
        strncpy( tag34,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag34) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"150") == 0 ){ 
        strncpy( tag150,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag150) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"11") == 0 ){  
        strncpy( tag11,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag11) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"41") == 0 ){  
        strncpy( tag41,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag41) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"43") == 0 ){   
        strncpy( tag43,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag43) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"48") == 0 ){  
        strncpy( tag48,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag48) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"207") == 0 ){  
        strncpy( tag207,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag207) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"55") == 0 ){   
        strncpy( tag55,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag55) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"167") == 0 ){  
        strncpy( tag167,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag167) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"200") == 0 ){ 
        strncpy( tag200,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag200) - 1 ) ;
    }else if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],"44") == 0 ){   
        strncpy( tag44,ArrRightVal[idx],sizeof(tag44) - 1 ) ;
    } .......
    ......
}//for
```

It works but very lousy ,  I like to know how to implement a 
c macro  so that I wont need so many if ...else.... ?!

The psudocode would be :

```
for(int idx=0;idx<inum;idx++){
    if( strlen(ArrLeftVar[idx]) < 1 )
        break ;
    int len = atoi( ArrLeftVar[idx] ) ;
    if( (funcptr = Exist(Func_#len)) != NULL )
        funcptr( ArrRightVal[idx] ) ;
}//for
```

then I have Func_34(char* ptr) , Func_150(char* ptr), ....
that make code cleaner .

How can I implement such template or macro , any hints ?!

Comment: Don't use `strncpy` until you've read and understood **exactly** what it does. And then don't use it. It is **not** a "safe" version of `strcpy`.

Comment: As you already noticed there is not language C/C++. But the different languages C and C++! Pick **one** and stick with it. That said, we are no coding or tutoring service.

Comment: There's no such language called "C/C++".

Comment: How are `tag34`, `tag150`, etc. defined?

Comment: Can't help but think `std::string` would make this much easier to write. I suggest going the C++ route.

Comment: Why not put tag0 ... tagwhatever in an array?

Comment: I smell the strong haut-gout of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: If this is the right code and you want to make it 'look' better, you can try to generate that using preprocessors macros.

Comment: Too far gone for that, Olaf. I think  we may have progressed into Y-Z

Comment: C++ has `std::map<std::string, std::string>` which does exactly this.

Comment: @user4581301: Whatever. There is no use wasting any time, until OP has understood C and C++ are different languages and decided which way to go. **And** clarified _what_ he wants to achieve actually.

Comment: @Peter , thanks for your strncpy warning .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a struct like this:

```
struct tags {
    const char *name;
    int maxlen;
    char value[128];
};

struct tags tagList[] = {
    { "34", 32, 0 },
    { "43", 16, 0 },
    { "11", 32, 0 },
    ...
};
```

Then you could write your loop like this:

```
for(int idx=0;idx<inum;idx++){
    if( strlen(ArrLeftVar[idx]) < 1 )
        break ;
    for (int tagIdx=0; tagIdx < (sizeof(tagList) / sizeof(tagList[0]); tagIdx++) {
        if( strcmp(ArrLeftVar[idx],tagList[tagIdx].name) == 0 ){ 
            strncpy(tagList[tagIdx].value,
                    ArrRightVal[idx],
                    tagList[tagIdx].maxlen - 1 );
            tagList[tagIdx].value[tagList[tagIdx].maxlen - 1] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If at any time you need to add/remove tags, you only have to change the tag list array instead of a large if/else block.